# Delete strings that contain only numbers from the rows of a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, google-colaboratory

My dataframe contains many lines consisting of:

- **Numbers only;**
- **Numbers and spaces;**
- **Strings mixed with numbers (see *Hell0 guys34 g00d j0b.*);**

```
+--------------------------+--------+
|   Content                | Score  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| Hello my name is Tim.    | 3      |
| 081332111333             | 4      |
| 08 97 5524               | 1      |
| 10 08 2021               | 1      |
| Great App                | 3      |
| Hell0 guys34 g00d j0b.   | 5      |
    . . . . . . . . . .      . . .
| 122345324 2331 111111    | 3      |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

Is there a way to clean up, that is to delete these 3 types of possible rows that appear in my dataframe, using the withColumn, or any other quick method? 
I had created a for loop that iterates over all my rows in the Dataframe, but being ***over 1 million rows***, it takes a long time.
***My environment is Google Colab*** 
***Thanks a lot!!***

Answer (score 0):

Using pyspark, I would simply do something like this:

```py
#assuming df is your dataframe
df.where(~df["content"].rlike("\d")).show()
```

> `\d` Matches any decimal digit. Equivalent to `[0-9]`.